# angular 7 template changes not reflecting in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular7

i am using angular 7 with MVC5 in visual studio 2019. i am facing a problem while rendering angular template in my index.cshtml.
i am accessing angular template in index.cshtml by using .
its load perfectly angular template in index.cshtml but when i make some changes in app.component.html these changes did not reflect in index.cshtml and its shows old default template in the browser. although i refresh cache and even disable cache in chrome but still loading old default template . i am unable to understand that why this default template is showing even though it not exist yet.  when i change the selector name it does not sjow any thing in my cshtml. 
here is my code

app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] })
export class AppComponent {
title = 'App';
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }


 <app-root></app-root>
```

bundle.config:

```
          bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bundles")
           .Include(
               "~/bundles/inline.*",
               "~/bundles/runtime.*",
               "~/bundles/zone.*",
               "~/bundles/polyfills.*",
               "~/bundles/scripts.*",
               "~/bundles/vendor.*",
               "~/bundles/main.*"));
                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles")
              .Include("~/bundles/styles.*"));
```

main.ts

```
   import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
   import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser- 
 dynamic';

  import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
  import { environment } from './environments/environment';

  if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  }

 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in VS Code. Build it using the ng build command in your terminal. After it is successfully built, reopen it in VS 2019 and run it. This basically compiles your angular files.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong because you don't run you angular app using CLi so you wont see the change if you don't run build command for your angular app

Run ng build (if you using Angular CLI) or using your build command to build angular app then refresh the browser to see the change

Comment: i have run the app using ng build  and ng serve -- open . Even after running these commands no changes reflect in my cshtml page. but when i open the app using ng serve --open it shows the changes in the browser but not picking up these changes in my MVC page.

Comment: @zia are you sure that when you reference "~/bundles/inline.*" like this is correct ?

Comment: thanks @Ngô Hùng Phúc  . i have resolved the problem. actually the output path in angular.json was not correctly mapped due to which changes was not reflecting.

Comment: Now i am facing an issue that after every change i have to build the angular project using ng build --prod after that the changes reflect in my cshtml page. is there any way to build it automatically when i run visual studio. i mean i don't want to build it every time to see even a single change in html.could you guide me ?

Comment: @zia you can also using built in template of Visual Studio 2019. There is .net core 2.2 with angular template